# How to excuite test classes in suite one after the other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation

I have written a test suite to execute all my test classes one after the other .
But the problem is that while executing , its taking the methods from both class and executing at once.

so i want to write a code where all methods in one class will be executed 
and later it will proceed to the next test class.

Test class code

```
from pages.Home.hamburger_page import HamburgerPage
from utilites.testStatus import TestStatus
import pytest
import unittest


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetUp", "setUp")
class hamburgerTest(unittest.TestCase):

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def classSetup(self, oneTimeSetUp):
    self.ha = HamburgerPage(self.driver)
    self.ts = TestStatus(self.driver)

@pytest.mark.run(order=1)
def test_hamburger_menu_latest_WAF021(self):
    result = self.ha.find_latest()
    self.ts.markFinal("To find latest link", result, "Click on latest link")

@pytest.mark.run(order=2)
def test_hamburger_menu_top__WAF022(self):
    result = self.ha.find_topics_links()
    self.ts.markFinal("To find top link", result, "Click on top link")

@pytest.mark.run(order=3)
def test_hamburger_menu_badges__WAF023(self):
    result = self.ha.find_badges()
    self.ts.markFinal("To find badges link", result, "Click on badges link")

@pytest.mark.run(order=4)
def test_hamburger_menu_users__WAF024(self):
    result = self.ha.find_users()
    self.ts.markFinal("To find user link ", result,"Click on users link")

@pytest.mark.run(order=5)
def test_hamburger_menu_groups__WAF025(self):
    result = self.ha.find_groups()
    self.ts.markFinal("To find groups link", result, "Click on groups link")

@pytest.mark.run(order=6)
def test_hamburger_menu_announcements__WAF026(self):
    result = self.ha.find_announcements()
    self.ts.markFinal("To find announcements link", result, "Click on announcements link")
```

Second Test

```
from pages.Home.topic_page import topicPage
from utilites.testStatus import TestStatus
import pytest
import unittest
import time

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetUp","setUp")
class TopicTest(unittest.TestCase):
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def classSetup(self,oneTimeSetUp):
    self.tp = topicPage(self.driver)
    self.ts = TestStatus(self.driver)

@pytest.mark.run(order=1)
def test_header_login(self):
    self.tp.find_header_logIn()

@pytest.mark.run(order=2)
def test_validLogin(self):
    self.tp.getelements("xxxxxx@xxx.com", "xxxxx")
    time.sleep(3)

@pytest.mark.run(order=3)
def test_FirstLinkInAnnouncements(self):
    self.tp.find_first_announcement_link()
    time.sleep(3)

@pytest.mark.run(order=5)
def test_TitleVerfication(self):
    self.tp.find_title()
    time.sleep(5)

@pytest.mark.run(order=4)
def test_ReplyDropDown(self):
    self.tp.find_scrollupfull()
    time.sleep(4)
    self.tp.find_topic_page_reply()
```

Test Suite

```
import unittest
from tests.Home.hamburger_test import hamburgerTest
from tests.Home.topic_test import TopicTest

# Get all tests from the test classes
tc1 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(hamburgerTest)
tc2 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TopicTest)

# Create a test suite combining all test classes

Test1 = unittest.TestSuite([tc1, tc2])


unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(Test1)
```

Comment: Why are you running `pytest` tests with `unittest`?

Comment: If there is other way to do ,please let me know since i am new to python i am implementing what ever i have learnt

Comment: In the command line, go to the directory with tests and execute command `pytest`.

Comment: Same thing i did still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you should execute tc1 and tc2 separately. for eg.

```
Test1 = unittest.TestSuite([tc1])
Test2 = unittest.TestSuite([tc2])

unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(Test1)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(Test2)
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: same problem  its simultaneously taking the methods from both class and executing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `pytest-ordering` plugin (https://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.io/en/develop/).
You're setting the order in which tests should be executed. It makes pytest execute tests from highest order (1) to lowest. Tests with the same order can be found in both classes, which is why pytest is jumping between classses.

Comment: But if i remove the ordering the test methods will not run according to the proper order ryt ? is there any other way i can order the test methods

Comment: To achieve this, set the "order" parameter of the first test in the second class to 7 and all following tests to 8, 9 and so on.

Comment: ya if i do this it working fine...... but i had do this to all my test class methods , in future if i had add any new  method to any of my class than again i have to do this same process from first (i mean changing the order of the execution)